# Incorrect update with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I encountered a problem that I just can not solve.
For example, I have the table with rows, id, season, episode, order.
Data in the table looks like:

```
+--------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| id     |     season    |     episode    |     order    |
+--------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| 153914 | 1             | 1              |         NULL |
| 153915 | 1             | 3              |         NULL |
| 153916 | 1             | 2              |         NULL |
| 153919 | 1             | 3              |         NULL |
| 153920 | 1             | 4              |         NULL |
| 153921 | 1             | 3              |         NULL |
+--------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

So, when I run SELECT query without UPDATE, row order is sorted absolutely correctly

```
SELECT id, season, episode, (@row:=@row+1) as order
                            FROM `shows`, (select @row:=0) as rc
                            WHERE `show_id`= 14670
                            ORDER BY CAST(season AS UNSIGNED) ASC, CAST(episode AS UNSIGNED) ASC

+--------+--------+---------+--------+
| id     | season | episode | order  |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+
| 153914 | 1      | 1       |      1 |
| 153916 | 1      | 2       |      2 |
| 153915 | 1      | 3       |      3 |
| 153919 | 1      | 3       |      4 |
| 153921 | 1      | 3       |      5 |
| 153920 | 1      | 4       |      6 |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+
```

But when I use the same query as the subquery of UPDATE statement it doesn't sort the same way and set different order values.

```
UPDATE `shows` f
JOIN
(
    SELECT id, (@row:=@row+1) as rowOrder
    FROM `shows` as Fl, (select @row:=0) as rc
    WHERE Fl.`show_id` = 14670
    ORDER BY Fl.season ASC, Fl.episode ASC
) t 
ON t.id = f.id 
SET f.order = t.rowOrder

mysql> SELECT id, season, episode, order FROM `shows`  WHERE `show_id`=14670;
+--------+--------+---------+--------+
| id     | season | episode | order  |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+
| 153914 | 1      | 1       |      1 |
| 153915 | 1      | 3       |      2 |
| 153916 | 1      | 2       |      3 |
| 153919 | 1      | 3       |      4 |
| 153920 | 1      | 4       |      5 |
| 153921 | 1      | 3       |      6 |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Please, explain to me why it happens and how to solve it.
MySQL version:

```
>mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: This isn't your actual query :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  It would appear that the `order by` is not affecting the variable.  I wonder if this has changed in recent versions of MySQL.  It certainly used to work.

In any case, you can fix it by using a subquery:

```
UPDATE shows s JOIN
       (SELECT id, (@row:=@row+1) as rowOrder
        FROM (SELECT id, sea
              FROM shows s2
              WHERE s2.show_id = 14670
              ORDER BY s2.season ASC, s2.episode ASC
             ) s2 CROSS JOIN
             (SELECT @row := 0) as rc
       ) s3
       ON s.id = s3.id 
    SET s.order = s3.rowOrder;
```

Comment: It works as supposed to, thank you! Is it some kind of MySQL bug or interpretation?

Comment: @RussellSk. . . . In my experience, variables never worked right with `GROUP BY`, and a subquery was necessary.  However, variables *did* work -- once upon a time -- with `ORDER BY`.  That seems to have changed as well.  This is part of MySQL's improved query processing engine -- there are more important things to optimize for than variables.